# Remover 'R$' antes de converter para Double

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma lista de produtos em uma tabela, e com intuito de deixa a interface mais amigável, na coluna 'preço' concatenei o 'R$' junto ao valor.
Agora eu preciso capturar esse valor para fazer uma operação matemática e preciso converter em float:

```
 //captura o valor da linha na table
var linha = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
// deve converter o valor para Float
var valor = parseFloat(linha.find('td:eq(1)').text());
```

Usando Jquery, como faço para remover os caracteres 'R$' e converter o valor em Float?

Comment: `parseFloat(linha.find('td:eq(1)').text().replace('R$',''))` não consegue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tenta [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559178/4551469):

```
var linha = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
var valor = Number(linha.find('td:eq(1)').text().replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));
```

Comment: A resposta pode funcionar, mas ao colocar "tente" vc não está dando uma resposta precisa. Além de não explicar o que foi proposto.

Comment: Obrigado @rLinhares, seu comentário acima não resolveu, mas ajudou a direcionar minha dúvida.
Para que outros desenvolvedores possam usar encontrei um link que possue a função de converter um valor String(moeda) para um float e o inverso também: 
https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/Funcoes-para-converter-de-moeda-para-float-e-viceversa